# modify an object with a addEventlistener

Tags: javascript, html

I have an array of objects which looks like this:

```js
0: {name: "a", id: 0, trash: false}
1: {name: "b", id: 1, trash: false}
2: {name: "c", id: 2, trash: false}
3: {name: "d", id: 3, trash: false}
4: {name: "e", id: 4, trash: false}
5: {name: "f", id: 5, trash: false}
```

and I wrote this code to change the value `trash` from `true` to `false` everytime I click.

```js
list.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  if (e.target.classList.contains("delete")) {
    e.target.parentElement.remove();
    console.log((listTodo[2].trash = true));
    console.log(listTodo);
  }
});
```

I know that writing in this way i's only going to chance the value of the specific object(in this case the object in the position 2).

So, what I'm trying to do is dig into the clicked object and change the value.

here is a snippet of the HTML part of the code to give an idea.

```html
<li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
<span>lorem1234</span><i class="far fa-trash-alt delete" job="delete" id=5></i>
</li>
```

Comment: `${todo}` is not javascript. Are you using some other technology? Please tag it or better to replace it with real html so we can run it here!

Comment: Use `data-job` instead of a non-standard `job` attribute. I’d recommend the same for the `id`. Okay, what is your question here? Simply get the `id` attribute and relace `[2]` with it.

Comment: @user1601324 _“`${todo}` is not javascript.”_ — That’s HTML. It doesn’t need to be JavaScript.

Comment: @user4642212 its not like any standard of HTML Ive ever seen!! What is it? Its not an element or attribute. I don't know what it is/

Comment: @user1601324 `${todo}` is simple text; it’s content of an element. I’m sure you’ve seen simple text before. If they are using any framework to replace `${todo}` with other text, it doesn’t matter, because the answer to this question is trivial DOM traversal.

Comment: its changed to give you a better idea, the HTML code was the template that I use in `innerHTML`

Comment: @user4642212 That is more than simple text. It is some sort of scripting maybe? But not HTML! How are we supposed to know the id when it is `${id}`? Is it a number that matches the index array? It is a text that we are to use to find the index? It is not helpful like this so yes it does matter !

Comment: I think now its more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use data attribute `data-job` as others have said, then you can do this with 3 steps in your javascript click handler.

- 1: check the clicked element has has the `data-job="delete"`. This is easy to do using the `dataset` attribute `if (e.target.dataset.job == "delete")`
- 2: Remove it from the DOM `e.target.parentElement.remove();`
- 3: Change the "trash" value in your array. You get the `id` of the clicked element `e.target.id` and use it as the array key: `listTodo[e.target.id].trash = true;`

That's all. The javascript function is next, then a snippet below that showing it working.

```
var list = document.getElementById("list");
list.addEventListener("click", (e) => {

    // Check if the clicked element has the data-job="delete"
    if (e.target && e.target.dataset.job == "delete") {

        // Remove the element from the DOM
        e.target.parentElement.remove();

        // set trash to true for this element in the array using this id as the array key
        listTodo[e.target.id].trash = true;
  }
});
```

```js
var listTodo = {
  0: {name: "a", id: 0, trash: false},
  1: {name: "b", id: 1, trash: false},
  2: {name: "c", id: 2, trash: false},
  3: {name: "d", id: 3, trash: false},
  4: {name: "e", id: 4, trash: false},
  5: {name: "f", id: 5, trash: false}
};

var list = document.getElementById("list");
list.addEventListener("click", (e) => {

  // check if the clicked element has the data-job="delete"
  if (e.target && e.target.dataset.job == "delete") {

    // Remove the clicked element from the DOM
    e.target.parentElement.remove();

    // Set trash=true for the clicked element using the id as the array key
    listTodo[e.target.id].trash = true;

    console.log ("Deleting element "+e.target.id);
  }

});
```

```css
i {  display: block;  height: 20px;  width: 20px; margin-left: 10px;}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<ul id="list">
  <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
    <span>0</span><i class="far fa-trash-alt delete" data-job="delete" id="0"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
    <span>1</span><i class="far fa-trash-alt delete" data-job="delete" id="1"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
    <span>2</span><i class="far fa-trash-alt delete" data-job="delete" id="2"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
    <span>3</span><i class="far fa-trash-alt delete" data-job="delete" id="3"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
    <span>4</span><i class="far fa-trash-alt delete" data-job="delete" id="4"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
    <span>5</span><i class="far fa-trash-alt delete" data-job="delete" id="5"></i>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hey thank you!!! this one also works too! thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use `data-*` attributes which are easy to read with `getAttribute` (or `data()` if you happen to use jQuery).

Then you can just read the `job` and `id` easily enough and convert the latter to an index of the array of `listTodo`.

```js
var listTodo = [{name: "a", id: 0, trash: false},
{name: "b", id: 1, trash: false},
{name: "c", id: 2, trash: false}];

var list = document.querySelector("#my-list");
list.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  if (e.target.getAttribute("data-job") == "delete") {
    e.target.parentElement.remove();
    var idx = parseInt(e.target.getAttribute("data-id"),10);
    console.log((listTodo[idx].trash = true));
    console.log(listTodo);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
<ul id="my-list">
<li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
<span>lorem1</span><i class="far fa-trash-alt delete" data-job="delete" data-id="0"></i>
</li>
<li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
<span>lorem2</span><i class="far fa-trash-alt delete" data-job="delete" data-id="1"></i>
</li>
<li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
<span>lorem3</span><i class="far fa-trash-alt delete" data-job="delete" data-id="2"></i>
</li>
</ul>
```